# mysql select UNION with AND problem

Tags: mysql

in database, the table friendship has id, username and friendusername. When a user accept other user as friend, 1 row of record will be saved in the table (not 2 rows). I want to random select 15 users and display their pictures, mysql code :

```
<?php
$query120 = "SELECT frenusername FROM friendship WHERE username='{$username2}' UNION SELECT username FROM friendship WHERE friendusername='{$username2}' AND RAND()<(SELECT ((15/COUNT(*))*10) FROM friendship) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15";
$result120 = mysql_query($query120,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
confirm_query($result120); 
while($userinfo120 = mysql_fetch_array($result120)){
    $frenusername= $userinfo120['frenusername'];
    $username = $userinfo120['username']; //this hold empty value, why?

    $query121 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username='{$frenusername} OR username='{$username}' LIMIT 1";
    //display picture
    }
}
?>
```

My problem 1 :
Why `$username` hold empty value?

My problem 2 :
The statement `AND RAND()<(SELECT ((15/COUNT(*))*10) FROM friendship) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15"` is to random select 15 records from the table. Supposedly I need to write it on both UNION statements right? (meaning I need to write it for 2 times). If so, it will show 30 records instead of 15 records. Should I change it become `8/Count LIMIT 8` for each? Or is there any other way avoid duplicate the AND statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a random set of 15 friends of a `username2`, then you don't need the `UNION`:

```
(SELECT username 
FROM friendship 
WHERE (friendusername='{$username2}' OR 
username='{$username2}') AND 
RAND()<(SELECT ((15/COUNT(*))*10) FROM friendship) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 15)
```

The [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) will select everything from either `SELECT`. In your SQL, the first `SELECT` would get ALL of the usernames in the friendship table, then the second `SELECT` would get the random 15, but the `UNION` would select from either of the two `SELECT`s a record if it was in either of the two `SELECT` results. That's probably why you're seeing the extra users.

Comment: In the OP's case the same user can be stored in `friendship` as either `username` or `friendusername`, and the OP wants to select random rows from both subsets, because they all contain different friends of `$username2`. So UNION (or, rather, UNION ALL) is necessary.

Comment: yes, i need UNION because I need to select 'friendusername' OR 'username' both (not only 'friendusername').